# Disable install for FetchContent

Tags: cmake

Let's say I have the following code:

```
include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(cmark
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/commonmark/cmark.git
  GIT_TAG        0.29.0
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(cmark)

target_link_libraries(hello_world cmark::cmark_static)
install(TARGETS hello_world DESTINATION bin)
```

That works correctly, but whenever I run `make install`, it also installs all the cmark files (like `include/cmark_version.h`, `lib/pkgconfig/libcmark.pc`, etc).

Is there any way to disable installing files from packages with FetchContent?

Answer (score 14):

The macro `FetchContent_MakeAvailable` includes subproject with use of `add_subdirectory` command. And this command has as special option - `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL` - for disable inner `install` calls.

So, you may replace call `FetchContent_MakeAvailable` with:

```
FetchContent_GetProperties(cmark)
if(NOT cmark_POPULATED)
  FetchContent_Populate(cmark)
  add_subdirectory(${cmark_SOURCE_DIR} ${cmark_BINARY_DIR} EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
endif()
```

(This is actually an exact alternative to `FetchContent_GetProperties` call noted in the [FetchContent documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.19/module/FetchContent.html) but with additional `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL` parameter.)

Comment: You can move to Fetch stuff to a subdirectory and include this with EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL. This way you can keep using FetchContent_MakeAvailable.

Answer (score 3):

Tsyvarev's answer works. Note though that [for CMake 3.28](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.28/release/3.28.html#modules), [`FetchContent_Declare`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.28/module/FetchContent.html#command:fetchcontent_declare) can take a parameter "`EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL`", which will have the same effect. Ex.

```
FetchContent_Declare(cmark
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/commonmark/cmark.git
  GIT_TAG        0.29.0
  # Other content options...
  EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL
)
```

For pre-CMake.3.28, use Tsyvarev's answer:

> ```
> FetchContent_GetProperties(cmark)
> if(NOT cmark_POPULATED)
>   FetchContent_Populate(cmark)
>   add_subdirectory(${cmark_SOURCE_DIR} ${cmark_BINARY_DIR} EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
> endif()
> ```

Comment: It's important to note that at the time of writing of both this comment and the original answer, [3.28 has not been fully released](https://cmake.org/download). It's still a release candidate