# How to use FetchContent_Populate with Eigen?

Tags: cmake, eigen, fetchcontent

I want to use `FetchContent` to automatically manage the dependency to Eigen for my project, which works in general. However, when using the recommended method of `FetchContent_Declare()` and `FetchContent_MakeAvailable()` a subsequent call to `install` also installs all Eigen headers and documentation which is not necessary in my case.

To circumvent this behavior, I tried the method suggested in this answer: [Disable install for FetchContent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65527126/disable-install-for-fetchcontent)

`FetchConten_Populate()` however fails to fill the variables `${Eigen_SOURCE_DIR}` and `${Eigen_BIN_DIR}` (which the documentation told me should happen) so that I cannot call `add_subdirectory()`.

Here is a minimal `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.12)

project (FetchContentExample)

include (FetchContent)

FetchContent_Declare(
  Eigen
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen.git
  GIT_TAG        3.4.0
)

FetchContent_GetProperties(Eigen)
if(NOT Eigen_POPULATED)
  FetchContent_Populate(Eigen)

  message("SRC; ${Eigen_SOURCE_DIR}") # Apparently empty?
  message("BIN: ${Eigen_BINARY_DIR}") # Apparently empty?

  add_subdirectory(${Eigen_SOURCE_DIR} ${Eigen_BINARY_DIR} EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
endif()

add_executable(FetchContentExample
  main.cpp
)

target_link_libraries (FetchContentExample
  PRIVATE
  Eigen3::Eigen
)

install(
  TARGETS FetchContentExample
  DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
  COMPONENT Runtime
)
```

The same setup works fine when I use e.g.

```
FetchContent_Declare(
  fmt
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt.git
  GIT_TAG        5.3.0
)
```

instead of Eigen.
What specifically am I doing wrong when it comes to Eigen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `FetchContent_Populate()` however fails to fill the variables `${Eigen_SOURCE_DIR}` and `${Eigen_BINARY_DIR}` (which the documentation told me should happen).

Actually, FetchContent fills variables `${eigen_SOURCE_DIR}` and `${eigen_BINARY_DIR}` which names are constructed from the **lowercase** variant of the project's name. This is written in the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html#command:fetchcontent_populate):

> FetchContent_Populate() will set three variables in the scope of the caller:
>
> `<lowercaseName>_POPULATED`
> This will always be set to TRUE by the call.
>
> `<lowercaseName>_SOURCE_DIR`
> The location where the populated content can be found upon return.
>
> `<lowercaseName>_BINARY_DIR`
> A directory intended for use as a corresponding build directory.

So the correct sequence of commands for EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL inclusion of Eigen would be:

```
FetchContent_GetProperties(Eigen)
if(NOT eigen_POPULATED)
  FetchContent_Populate(Eigen)

  add_subdirectory(${eigen_SOURCE_DIR} ${eigen_BINARY_DIR} EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
endif()
```