CMake: clear all install rules?
In my CMake-based project, I include another library as a subdir:
list(PREPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)
set(LIBIGL_INSTALL OFF)
include(libigl)
# cmake/libigl.cmake contains:
#include(FetchContent)
#FetchContent_Declare(
#    libigl
#    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/libigl/libigl.git
#    GIT_TAG v2.5.0
#)
#FetchContent_MakeAvailable(libigl)

then my CMake builds something using libigl, and installs it.
But libigl's CMake is installing also some Eigen header files, which I do not want.
This is happening because in libigl/cmake/recipes/external/eigen.cmake install(...) commands are added unconditionally.
Ideally I'd wrap those lines in if(EIGEN_INSTALL) ... endif(), but I have no control over that (well, I could add PATCH_COMMAND remove-eigein-install-commands.patch UPDATE_DISCONNECTED 1 to cmake/libigl.cmake FetchContent_Declare(...), which sits in my repository, as a last resort).
Can I instead remove all the previously created install rules (e.g. just before adding mine)?

No, it is not possible to remove previously issued install rules. For other approaches to disabling installation of a subproject see the duplicate question.

@Tsyvarev I'm not using add_subdirectory(...), I'm using FetchContent_MakeAvailable(...). Perhaps this is more relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65527126/disable-install-for-fetchcontent But thank you that pointed me into the right direction.

Ok, I have added your link to the duplicate list. As pointed by my answer, FetchContent_MakeAvailable is effectively add_subdirectory. But yes, FetchContent has its own features.
